# Insert row for each date within range

Tags: php, mysql, sql

In my MySQL database, I want to insert table rows for each day within a specific date range (1 july 2014 to 1 july 2015). Each row has a set of different values, but only two of them need to be set (date & status), the other values should remain NULL.

Is there any way I can achieve this?

Thanks!

Comment: `insert into foo (date, status, argle, bargle) values (now(), 'hungry', null, null)`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you want to insert the same status for every day in this range, you could use:

```
INSERT INTO your_table (date, status, col3, col4)
SELECT
    DATE_ADD('2014-07-01', INTERVAL t.n DAY),
    'your status',
    NULL,
    NULL
FROM (
    SELECT 
        a.N + b.N * 10 + c.N * 100 AS n
    FROM
        (SELECT 0 AS N UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3 UNION ALL SELECT 4 UNION ALL SELECT 5 UNION ALL SELECT 6 UNION ALL SELECT 7 UNION ALL SELECT 8 UNION ALL SELECT 9) a
       ,(SELECT 0 AS N UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3 UNION ALL SELECT 4 UNION ALL SELECT 5 UNION ALL SELECT 6 UNION ALL SELECT 7 UNION ALL SELECT 8 UNION ALL SELECT 9) b
       ,(SELECT 0 AS N UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3 UNION ALL SELECT 4) c
    ORDER BY n
) t   
WHERE
    t.n <= TIMESTAMPDIFF(DAY, '2014-07-01', '2015-07-01');
```

**Explanation**

The subselect creates a temporary table with a row for every day between start ('2014-07-01') and end ('2015-07-01'). So MySQL has only to do one single INSERT and this is much faster than a row by row insert.

Comment: This works like a charm and is very fast. For the life of me I can't figure out what that subselect is doing with all those UNIONs though.

Answer (score 1):

DECLARE @StartDate DATE = '7/1/2014'

DECLARE @EndDate DATE = '7/1/2015'

CREATE TABLE #TempTable

(

```
MyDate DATE,

MyStatus INT,

MyData INT,

MyData2 VARCHAR(5)
```

)

WHILE (@StartDate <= @EndDate)

```
BEGIN

    INSERT INTO #TempTable

            ( MyDate, MyStatus, MyData, MyData2 )

    VALUES  ( @StartDate, -- MyDate - date

          8, -- MyStatus - int

              NULL, -- MyData - int

              NULL  -- MyData2 - varchar(5)

              )

    SET @StartDate = DATEADD(DAY, 1, @StartDate)

END
```